# Comentário em arquivos .env

Tags: javascript, node.js, variáveis-de-ambiente

Exite alguma maneira de escrever comentários em arquivo .env em projetos em NodeJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A aplicação só olha as chaves que você determinar então você pode colocar, por exemplo, o caractere `#` na frente do comentário sem problemas

Comment: Valeu. Nenhum erro mostrado. Deu certo. 0/